# Высота тега Body - HTML (почему так?)

Tags: html, css

Доброго всем дня.
Сделал следующее:

```
<body style="margin:0; padding:0px; background-image: url('images/bg_for_pages.jpg'); border: solid 1px #FF0000;">
```

И увидел, что тег body заканчивается не на max.высота браузера (FireFox), а по контенту.
Т.е. он не заполняет всё окно браузера. Как такое возможно?

---

Даже параметр height:100%; не исправил ситуации.

Answer (score 4):

[[@I_CaR](/users/3547/i_car)](/users/3547/i_car), чтобы это работало, у всех предков выбранного тэга должна быть указана высота.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/3v8zZ/1/)** (серым цветом залит тэг **body**)

Comment: Предок у body только ведь один - html? Я вообще его за тег к которому привинчивать параметры можно не рассматривал ни когда.  
Но я по вашему варианту делал, не помогло.  
Ещё что заметил, это если
    
    body {
border: solid 1px #FF0000;
background: #ffffdd;;
}

то border заканчивается раньше площади самого окна браузера по высоте, но вот его заливка срабатывает на 100% по высоте.

рабочий пример можно увидеть здесь:  
http://icar.bget.ru/view.php?id=98  
там нижний переход полутени заканчивается раньше страницы.

Comment: ---
P.S. Спасибо, ваша мысль натолкнула на выход.  
Снял градиентный background с body и повесил его на html.

Comment: **Web-программирование, это 2+2=(всё зависит от браузера и его версии).**

Answer (score 1):

Для html задается min-height:100% и position:relative;
Для body - если нужно, чтобы было только по высоте окна - height:100%. Если нужно, чтобы тянулось и ниже за html-ом, то тоже min-height:100%

```
html {
  position:relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  height:100%;
}
```